# How to create Spring Login with Email?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring and learning through. I am stuck on a login page using user Email. I am able to create login using UserName and Password using **jdbc-user-service**. But now I would like to change login using **UserEmail**.

Sample Configuration for UserName and Password Login as below:

```
<security:form-login login-page="/login"
    default-target-url="/product/productList/all" authentication-failure-url="/login?error"
    username-parameter="username" password-parameter="password" />
<security:logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
</security:http>
<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
            authorities-by-username-query="SELECT username, authority FROM authorities WHERE username = ?"
            users-by-username-query="SELECT username, password, enabled FROM users WHERE username = ?" />
        <security:password-encoder ref="bcryptEncoder" />
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

Login Form as below:

```
<form name="loginForm" action="<c:url value="/j_spring_security_check" />" method="post">

    <c:if test="${not empty error}">
        <div class="error" style="color: #ff0000;">${error}</div>
    </c:if>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">UserName : </label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Passwrod:</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default">
    <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
</form>
```

How can I change to Authenticate User with Email and also bind with User Authorization, too? Please help me to get a demo tutorial.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried changing the SQL queries so that you select on the email address rather than the usrename.

Example: `.. WHERE emailaddress` rather than `.. WHERE username`